# fedora can not boot - sendmail sm-client exim abandoned

Tags: fedora, sendmail, boot, exim

I am having an issue with booting fedora. it hangs with error message:

```
sendmail sm-client exim abandoned unknown malformed or incomplete option -L
```

how can i fix the issue ? is there any way to exclude sendmail from boot init ? but cant boot and login to fedora, no idea how to proceed.

thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Comment: Sendmail has a -L option, which Exim doesn't have, and Fedora assume that the MTA will understand that option. Given that Fedora allow switching the MTA, this is a Fedora bug and should be reported as such.

For Exim, I've filed http://bugs.exim.org/1117 to implement -L.  We'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may actually be with exim.

You should boot into single user mode and then:

```
chkconfig sendmail off
chkconfig exim off
```

to stop sendmail/exim from starting via init.